# jQuery Mobile Table Reflow & Column Toggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to have a table that is set data-mode="reflow" and data-mode="columntoggle" ?

Or I suppose is it possible to have two different data modes on an object?

Answer (score 0):

The reflow table does not need the data-mode attribute because is the default widget when you use the data-role="table" attribute.

Check http://api.jquerymobile.com/table-reflow/ in section **Applying reflow mode to a table**

If you specify data-mode="reflow" it will have the same effect as not writting it. The framework will check for a word that matches reflow or columntoggle so writing "reflow columntoggle" will not have the desired effect.

Comment: I think the question is whether reflow and columntoggle be used *together* or only independently of each other?

Comment: @nachtigall JQuery mobile test the mode of the widget using strict comparisson `!==`, this is why writting "reflow columntoggle" will not work. Besides that, both "reflow" and "columntoggle" are defined as separate widgets that inherit from the "mobile.table" widget. They both extend the same  methods like `_create` and `_rebuild` from their parent so I don't think a combination of their functionality is possible.